# Using line integrals to find total surface area

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, line-integrals

I am given the equation for the height of a fence, which is h(x,y,z) = 4 + ((sinx)/2) + (y/3) +z. The line integral of this function will give the lateral surface area of one side of the fence. However, I need to find the total surface area of the fence; does that mean that I will have to double the line integral, or do I need to do more to take into account the top of the fence too?

Comment: The problem as stated is not clear.  Ask your teacher.  I would simply answer:  "area of one side = xx, area of two sides = 2 xx$ and compute xx.  The problem certainly cannot involve the top of the fence because that information isn't given.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is much bigger than the one/two faces. The line integral of a function
$$h:\Bbb R^3\longrightarrow\Bbb R$$
without more information **doesn't makes any sense**. And the same $h$ as the *height* of the curve **doesn't makes any sense**.

More information is required. Namely, the projection on the plane $XY$, say
$$\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2.$$
Now, the (scalar) line integral of
$$h:\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R.$$
makes sense and will be...